# PropertyChanged remains null even if the property has been changed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am struggling with this for a while and I cannot figure it out. I have a button and a textBox. The textBox is linked to a property named: MessageDisplay. I want to be able to access this property and update the textBox in several places. Sadly, the PropertyChanged is null. The weird thing is that if I copy/paste the *MessageDisplayModel* class into the *MessageViewModel * class, it works ...

here is my code : 
XAMLfile :

```xml
<Grid>
    <Button Command="{Binding DisplayTextCommand}" Name="DisplayTextCommand"  Margin="53,72,544.6,286" Width="Auto">Push</Button>
    <TextBox Name="MessageDisplay" Text="{Binding MessageDisplay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
</Grid>
```

MessageDisplayModel file

```cs
public class MessageDisplayModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _message;
        public string MessageDisplay
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set
            {
                this._message = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("MessageDisplay");
            }
        }

        public void UpdateTextBox(string output)
        {
            MessageDisplay = output;
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }//class
```

MessageViewModel file:

```cs
public class MessageViewModel
    {
        private ICommand _testCommand;
        public MessageDisplayModel MessageDisplaySmt = new MessageDisplayModel();

        public ICommand DisplayTextCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand(DisplayMessage);
            }
            set
            {
                if (_testCommand == value) return;
                _testCommand = value;
            }
        }

        public void DisplayMessage()
        {
            MessageDisplaySmt.UpdateTextBox("Successfuly downloaded");
        }

    }//class
```

MainWindow file

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageDisplay.DataContext = new MessageDisplayModel();
            DisplayTextCommand.DataContext = new MessageViewModel();
        }
    }//class
```

I update the MessageDisplay property by using the method UpdateTextBox(string). I call this method on the click of the button. **When debugging the property gets updated but when time comes to notify the UI that the property has changed, *PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged* has its value null** ... But if I write something in the textBox, the *PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged* gets changed and isn't null anymore. All I want is to be able to change the textBox's property whenever I want and from anywhere I want to. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different instances of `MessageDisplayModel`. You must use a shared instance.

Also the `DisplayTextCommand` is implemented "wrong". The `set` method is redundant as the property's `get` always returns a new instance of the `ICommand`.

**MessageViewModel.cs**

```
public class MessageViewModel
{
  pulic MessageViewModel()
  {
  }

  pulic MessageViewModel(MessageDisplayViewModel messageDisplayViewModel)
  {
    this.MessageDisplaySmt = messageDisplayViewModel;
  }

  public void DisplayMessage()
  {
    this.MessageDisplaySmt.UpdateTextBox("Successfuly downloaded");
  }

  public MessageDisplayViewModel MessageDisplaySmt { get; set; }

  public ICommand DisplayTextCommand { get => new DelegateCommand(DisplayMessage); }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // Alternatively use XAML to set the DataContext (see MainWindow.xaml). Would require a parameterless constructor.
    this.DataContext = new MessageViewModel(new MessageDisplayViewModel());
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>

  <!-- 
    Alternative DataContext declaration using XAML instead of C#. 
    Requires a parameterless constructor for both view model objects. 
  -->
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MessageViewModel>
      <MessageViewModel.MessageDisplaySmt>
        <MessageDisplayViewModel />
      </MessageViewModel.MessageDisplaySmt>
    </MessageViewModel>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding DisplayTextCommand}" 
            Content="Push" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MessageDisplaySmt.MessageDisplay}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @BionicCode, you have been a great help. Also, thanks for the comment related to the "DisplayTextCommand ", it was indeed set up the wrong way.